# Is it possible to use the same nuxt child route in multiple parent pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

The same way a child components can be used in several parents, could the same nuxt-child route be used in more than one parent?

Comment: Try to edit and more information. What are you calling nuxt-child?
And what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by refactoring the page as a component and rendering the component on multiple pages.

`components/MyPageComponent.vue`

```html
<template>
   <h1>Your content here.</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// do your script stuff here
</script>
```

`pages/parent/page.vue`

```html
<template>
   <MyPageComponent />
</template>
```

`pages/other-parent/page.vue`

```html
<template>
  <MyPageComponent />
</template>
```